# Powershell -LiteralPath with wildcard

Tags: powershell

Since the filename has square brackets, I need to use `-LiteralPath`. However by doing so, I lost the ability to use wildcard (to include any file extension) in my code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath "$somepath"
foreach ($f in $files){
    Test-Path -LiteralPath "$somepath\$($f.BaseName).*" -PathType Leaf
}
```

One of the files is `file1 [123].txt` and `Test-Path` fails for this file. How can fix this behavior?
[image: Test-Path fails for file [123].txt]

As suggested by @Wasif:
[image: Suggested solution 1]
[image: Suggested solution 2]

Comment: from what i can tell, you will need to add a pipeline filter step to your `$Files =` call.

Comment: That's true and will works if I know the extension of the file beforehand. But I'm trying to avoid that as the files will not always have the same file type all the times.

Comment: um, er, what do you mean by that? [*frown*] your current item gets ALL files at the location ... the the path is the ONLY thing the `-LiteralPath` works on. there is no need to know the file _extension_ at all in any stage of the problem you have described.

Comment: um yes I do. Take a look at the attached image in edited question

Comment: ah! i misunderstood your intent. [*blush*] i thot you wanted to apply the `-LiteralPath` parameter to the directory name, not the file name. it looks like the only way to work this is to use `-Path` & `-Filter` for the dir and the extension ... then pipe to `Where-Object` to get the file names with brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
Test-Path 'file1 ``[123].*'
```

```
foreach ($f in $files){
    $path = "$somepath\$($f.BaseName).*".Replace('[', '``[')
    Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Leaf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "$somepath\$($f.BaseName).*" you can directly use full path of the file system object from $files variable itself i.e. **$files.FullName** I hope the following code works for you :)

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath "$somepath"
$files | ForEach-Object {Test-Path -LiteralPath $_.FullName -PathType Leaf}
```

Comment: That just completely ignored the wildcard where I want include ANY file extension...

Comment: Are you trying to filter the files by hard-coding the file extension ? or provide some insights about your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You're just close, just put the wildcard part in -Filter parameter and remove -PathType

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath "$somepath"
foreach ($f in $files){
    Test-Path -LiteralPath "$somepath" -Filter "$($_.BaseName).*"
}
```

But you can use -Path like this:

```
-Path `"$somepath\$($_.basename).*`"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still didn't do the check correctly. Edited the question with the result of your method.

Comment: Check the edited answer. On removal of PathType it returns true.

Comment: Removing that will return true for anything even though not its name, for example: `Test-Path -LiteralPath "D:\" -Filter "file.*"` will also return as true. Hmmm

Comment: That's hard why don't you use just -Path ?

Comment: Because if the filename contains any square brackets `[]`, `-Path` will fails.

Comment: I have shown a way to use -Path even if you have square brackets in file name

Comment: that still failed with error, check out the edited question